# Problems to read a PDF with iText7 (work with iText5)

Tags: java, itext, version

Here is the code to read a PDF with iText5, and it works :

```
public class CreateTOC {

  public static final String SRC = "file.pdf";

  class FontRenderFilter extends RenderFilter {
      public boolean allowText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
          String font = renderInfo.getFont().getPostscriptFontName();
          return font.endsWith("Bold") || font.endsWith("Oblique");
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
      new CreateTOC().parse(SRC);
  }

  public void parse(String filename) throws IOException {
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1000, 1000);
      RenderFilter regionFilter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
      FontRenderFilter fontFilter = new FontRenderFilter();
      TextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(
            new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), regionFilter, fontFilter);
      System.out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 56, strategy));
      reader.close();
  }
```

}

Can someone help me to do it working in iText7 ? There are problems with the Rectangle and the TextExtractionStrategy (it's not the same constructor as iText5)

Edit : RenderFilter isn't available in iText7...

Comment: *"RenderFilter isn't available in iText7"* - `IEventFilter` (and the implementation `TextRegionEventFilter`) quite likely is what you are looking for.